# Loading Xbox Live Avatar Model in Windows Phone 7 using XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

Does anybody know how to access the Xbox Live Avatar from within an XNA based Windows Phone 7 application?

Examples I have found seem to use a SignedInGamer.Avatar property, but this is not accessible from Windows Phone 7.

Is there another way or is this not possible in the first place?

as a side note, I'm using the recent Mango beta 7.1 SDK

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is they are only available to  partners.  See this post for more information:
http://www.ozymandias.com/how-do-i-use-xbox-live-apis-on-windows-phone

However, it looks like you can demo them, here's a quick tutorial on using them:
http://xnaessentials.com/archive/2009/06/11/xna-game-studio-3-1-avatar-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It's not available in code unless you have the elevated privileges of access to XBox live.

You can, however get an image of your avatar from the web. try:
http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/XXXXXXX/avatar-body.png

where xxxxx is the XBox account name. e.g. http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/kris/avatar-body.png